# Typeface similar to Papyrus with bold and italics

Tags: font-recommendation

I use the [Papyrus typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus_%28typeface%29) for some creative writing I am doing.

Except for the rough edges, I like all aspects of the typeface. Unfortunately, it doesn't come with different weights or italics.

I would like the proposed typeface to be available for non-commercial use without purchase if possible.

Comment: Because this question got a close vote, I wonder if it would be better to add the characteristics you like about Papyrus (or where you intend to use it, for example). That should make the font-recommendation easier :)

Comment: Few typefaces that are designed to mimic handwriting will come with a variety of weights and styles because that's how handwriting works--we tend to have just one style.

Comment: @DA01That is a good point, but I am still surprised that one wouldn't see the benefit of versatility by having alternative weights and styles.

Comment: If you're writing calligraphy, making a different weight is easy, simply use a wider or narrower nib on your pen.

Answer (score 2):

These are all paid fonts, slightly similar to Papyrus but with more weights available to them:

[FF Clair](https://www.fontshop.com/families/ff-clair) (Many weights)

[image]

[Corballis Sans](https://www.fontshop.com/families/corvallis-sans) (2 styles)

[image]

[ITC Tempus Sans](https://www.fontshop.com/families/itc-tempus-sans) (Many weights)

[image]